# Hi i'm having troubles with my internet

Tags: wireless, nvidia, internet, ethernet

I am using a ethernet cable to connect my pc to the internet and it says i'm connected but nothing will load it says something about the server not found.

My wifi card is: TL-WN-781ND

my gfx card is a gtx 950

version of ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you able to ping any website?

Comment: Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and write `ping 8.8.8.8`. What is the output?

Comment: network is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your access point / router / modem is not connected to the internet. You are connecting to it, so you have some kind of network running, but if there's no internet connection you cannot reach anything beyond your router. Check your router, restart it and if it says that it has no internet connection call your Internet Service Provider.

If you have wifi enabled, try to see if your smartphone can connect and have an internet connection. If this is the case, your cable may not be correctly inserted. Make sure to test the connection of the cable on both your computer and the machine you connect it to.

If you can test the computer in another network with the cable connection go ahead and do it. This will allow you to discard a ethernet card or cable error.

You should try with another cable to make sure that it is not the cable that is faulty.

If you or a friend have another computer at hand with an ethernet port, try it too, this will help you find out if it is a problem with your computer or with the network.

Comment: Ok I can connect to the internet on my smart phone so can my family on their own smart phones 

my mums laptop can use the same ethernet cable ive used 3 different ethnernet cables.

when you say restart my moderm do i flick the on/off switch or do i push the little button that resets the moderm?

Comment: Good. At least you know that the Internet connection works :) To reboot: power down the electricity and wait a few seconds to make sure that there's no electricity in it. Then power it up again. Do they have any other computers with ethernet cables that you can test with? I know it is cumbersome, but debugging this kind of issues comes down to eliminating things one by one.

Comment: One more thing: when you look at the lights in your ethernet connection right where you plug your cable (both on your computer and modem), are any lights lit? With which color?

Comment: When I plug it into my PC the light is yellow same with the modem lights, but for now I'll have to wait till tomorrow to try you're first option as my pc is in the study and the study is next to my parents room and they are sleeping but thanks! I'll try this and let you know

Comment: Also we only have 2 Ethernet cables, 1 is used for the wifi extender one's not used

Comment: You should have a fixed light (it indicates that it is connected) and the other one should flicker with data activity.  If you only have one light it should flicker with activity. It does not seem as there is a standard for the light colors, but green is always best :)

Comment: What does it say in the ethernet port you are using? If you could post a picture or add a link to a picture of these ports it would be helpful.